# How do I fix HttpRuntime.get_UsingIntegratedPipeline() method not found exception?

Tags: .net, asp.net, url-rewriting

This is the exception that I am getting when I run my application with the [Managed Fusion Url Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com) installed.

**Exception Details:** System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean System.Web.HttpRuntime.get_UsingIntegratedPipeline()'.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
 [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean System.Web.HttpRuntime.get_UsingIntegratedPipeline()'.]
   ManagedFusion.Rewriter.RewriterModule.context_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Projects\Managed Fusion (Open Source)\ManagedFusion.Rewriter\Source\RewriterModule.cs:162
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +64
```

I have .NET 2.0 SP1 installed on my server that is throwing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **install .NET 2.0 SP2**, this method was added to indicate to programs if the program is running under Integrated Pipeline mode (IIS 7.0+) or not (IIS 6.0).